# how to find the attached ebs volume for an instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Is there a way to find ebs volume id attached to a instance given the ec2 instanceid
something like

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/????
```

or aws-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the aws-cli, you could do this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids xxxxxxxx
```

where xxxxxxx, is the instance id you are after. It will give you a lot more information that just the ebs volumne id, but it is in there for you to parse out.